# What is wrong with the SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to use PDO, so i got this together:

So, `$_GET['word'] = "Jimi Hendrix"` and `$_GET['cat'] = "music"`.

```
$now = htmlentities(rawurldecode($_GET['word']));
$cat = htmlentities($_GET['cat']); 

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=DATABASE;host=localhost';
$user = "USER";
$password = "PASS";

# connect to the database
try {
    $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
                $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

                # the data to select 
                $data = array($cat, $now);

                $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM ? WHERE name LIKE ?");
                $STH->execute($data);
    $result = $STH->fetchAll();

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Uh-Oh, something wen't wrong. Please try again later.";
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

But the code above is returning:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You Have a Syntax error in your SQL near ''music' WHERE name LIKE 'Jimi Hendrix'' on line 1
```

Comment: _Off-Question-Topic:_ `name LIKE 'Jimi Hendrix'` is similar to `name = 'Jimi Hendrix'`... you could change that to `name LIKE '%Jimi Hendrix%'` to also find 'Somebody feat. Jimi Hendrix (live at Somewhere)'. Also, I'd squeeze `name` and `word` to lowercase, so you won't have problems in the case-department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The category is converted into a string and when the query is prepared it is converted into:

`SELECT id, name FROM 'cat' WHERE name 'music'`

The table shouldn't be a string, what you can do is:

```
# the data to select 
$data = array($now);

$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM $cat WHERE name LIKE ?");
$STH->execute($data);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't pass the table name as a parameter for the query. You'd need to construct/execute a dynamic SQL string.

Comment: Damm. You mean:

if($cat == "music"){...FROM music WHERE...}
if($cat == "movies"){...FROM movies WHERE...}

?

Comment: And when you do so, be very cautious and aware of the potential for SQL injection... i.e. validate that the string you are inserting as a table name contains only characters valid in a table name.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably because you are trying to insert the table name as a parameter. You may be able to do this as a stored procedure if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you cannot parameterize a table name with PDO (Or any other SQL interface that I know of).

You used to be able to find table naming conventions here:

http://www.mysql.com/doc/en/Legal_names.html

But it's been Larry Ellisowned.

I'd recommend finding a regex to validate MySQL table names and using that. A basic regex would be:

```
/[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*/
```

But that wont account for reserved words.