# mysqli Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: mysqli, bind, param

I have a problem with a prepared statement, here is my code:

```
function query_array($table, $data) {
    foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
        $columns[] = sprintf("`%s` = '%s'", $column, $this->db->real_escape_string($value));
    }
    $column_list = join(',', $columns);

    // Prepare the statement
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `?` SET ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $table, $column_list);

    // Execute the statement
    $stmt->execute();

    // Save the affected rows
    $affected = $stmt->affected_rows;

    // Close the statement
    $stmt->close();

    // ...
}
```

$this->db returns an object;

$table = 'settings'; (string)

$column_list: (string)

```
`title` = 'Socialsd',`captcha` = '0',`public` = '',`private` = '',`time` = '1',`perpage` = '10',`message` = '140',`mail` = '1',`inter` = '10000',`size` = '1048576',`format` = 'png,jpg,gif',`sizeMsg` = '1048576',`formatMsg` = 'png,jpg,gif,bmp',`censor` = '',`ad1` = '',`ad2` = ''
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line
>   1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\includes\classes.php:256 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\new\sources\admin.php(225):
>   updateSettings->query_array('settings', Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\new\index.php(42): PageMain() #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\new\includes\classes.php on line 256

I can't figure out what causes this, because trying the following works just fine:

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE `%s` SET %s", $table, $column_list);
$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Update 1**: May I know why this has been down-voted? It would be nice to know.

**Update 2**: So I've removed the last bind ($column_list) and put in the statement the entire output of $column_list, so basically I was binding only the table name, and now I get another error:

> Can't find file: '.\diary\@003f.frm' (errno: 22)

Now I'm really confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli :: prepare SQL error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11559186/1409082).

Comment: @Jocelyn Thanks for the comment, even if I manually set the table name to `settings` the error still persist, the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer here: [Use one bind_param() with variable number of input vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793471/use-one-bind-param-with-variable-number-of-input-vars) and also as @Jocelyn linked me, I've found that table names can't be binded. Can be closed.